# Ruby on Rails, select box with multiple selected, insert into db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, ruby-on-rails-4

I have model, where users can be apart of multiple projects, and projects can have multiple users. They are joined by a table called project_users.
In my new project form, I have a select box displaying all usernames of current users, and multiple usernames can be selected. How do I add an entry into project_users for each user that is selected? (or if there is a better way to model my data, please let me know...)

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :project_users
     has_many :users, :through => :project_users
end

class ProjectUser < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_one :project 
     has_one :user
     belongs_to :project
     belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :project_users
    has_many :users, :through => :project_users
end
```

In my project _form.html.erb i have:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= "Users assigned to project" %>
    <%= select_tag("user[user_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(User.find(:all), 'id', 'username')) %>
</div>
```

this populates the select box with the usernames of all users.

projects_controller.rb

```
def create
@project = Project.new(project_params)

@project_count = Project.count + 1

@project_user = ProjectUser.new
@project_user.user_id = current_user.id
@project_user.project_id = @project_count

respond_to do |format|
  if @project.save

    if @project_user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @project }
        else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end

    format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @project }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, :user_id)
end
```

I am new to Ruby on Rails, so any help would be awesome (or links to relevant articles, that i haven't managed to stumble across in my past 2 hours of trying to figure this out...)

I have now updated my code, which works and now adds the user to project_users! However now, i only have a drop down box, which means i can only select one user per project. Is there anyway to have a select box, where multiple users can be selected? Or will I have to edit the project, and have them added to project_users one at a time?

Comment: Kindly share your controller where the association is created

Comment: Have edited to show the create method in projects_controller.. Is this enough or should I put in the whole controller?

Comment: Project Params please

Comment: Have you added the foreign keys migrations?  Please do `rails console` and then at the console just type `Project` <return> and also `User` <return> and add the output to show the current model-table structure

Comment: Have added project params, console is giving me : 2.0.0-p451 :002 > Project
 => Project (call 'Project.connection' to establish a connection) 
2.0.0-p451 :003 > User
 => User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection)

Comment: and what are the actual params that are received by the controller?

Comment: {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"GDYgVhMXnBJjKWwHU4rvOa9jpS7XeoLPhEWktXurglI=",
 "project"=>{"name"=>"worrrrk?",
 "description"=>"worrrrk?"},
 "user"=>{"user_id"=>"4"},
 "commit"=>"Create Project"}

Comment: and in case of multiple users, you get multiple user_id in user hash?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you use the rails helpers like

```
options_from_collection_for_select
```

or

```
options_for_select
```

The main thing with rails is to follow the rules and conventions and use the helpers like this instead of manually trying to code up the same thing.  I recently heard it referred to as 'going off the rails' and it was the first time that the 'rails' part of ruby on rails made sense to me!

Comment: using the following, i now have a dropdown box... but it is still not working, it isnt adding the row to project_users.... <%= select_tag("user[user_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(User.find(:all), 'id', 'username')) %>

Comment: Thankyou for this, i have now update the original question with updated code.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it as I don't have the setup on my home pc, but it will be something like this.
`@project = Project.new(name: params[:name], description: params[:description])
 params[user_id].to_a.each do |user_id|
     @project.project_users.build(user_id: user_id)
 end`

Comment: Thankyou! I have now edited the post including what you have suggested.. Is there anyway to do with with a select box? Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to tell us what is in the models as well, the attributes, because now you are assigning current user as the project_user, which reading your initial problem I don't think is what you want, you basically want to create a project and associate the existing users with it through ProjectUser model, right?

Comment: You are right, that is my mistake. When multiple users are selected, the id's are passed through the params as follows: project[name]:ugggh
project[description]:ugggh
project[user_ids][]:
project[user_ids][]:1
project[user_ids][]:3
project[user_ids][]:4
commit:Create Project

Comment: sorry I was not on my seat, if you can give me your Skype id I might get a better idea of how to set it up